# Get node creation time in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase store the timestamp of when a node was created (not updated)? If it does, how do you obtain this given a node ref?

*I could just easily write a timestamp when creating nodes but I'd rather use something baked in if available.

Comment: It seems you are looking for the common row in a sql table, created_at and updated_at, using Firebase Functions, you can add it as backend logic. Then you can use it for pagination or other, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45757566/4017501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no auto-created metadata in Firebase about when a node was created, update, who created it, etc. If you have a need for such data, you can add it either by writing the local timestamp or by [writing a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps).

Comment: In the migration guide of Functions there is `const timestamp = context.timestamp;` I'm wondering if that also means that I can get the original timestamp for onUpdate https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#sdk_changes_that_affect_all_background_non_http_functions

Comment: Frank, it's looks like a very good idea to store metadata as a date of node creation. It's could be avoid redundant writing to DB and, as a result, reduce data transfer to subscribers of the node. In my case, I can even get deadly node while trying to write server date to node, because callback in Functions may be running for some seconds and user have time to delete the node, as a result server date will be written to new node with no data.